# Blurring black and white matrix with blur() results in colorful edges

Tags: c++, opencv, blur

I have a cv::Mat that is filled with ones and zeros. Its a simple curved black path on a white background. 
I want to blur the image using cv::blur as follows:

```
cv::Mat result;

cv::blur(curvePath, result, cv::Size(10, 10));
```

The curved path is constructed as follows, with completeBandPath being a cinder::Path2d instance that encloses the area that is supposed to be black (or zeros):

```
Rectf bb = completeBandPath.calcPreciseBoundingBox();

const int matHeight = static_cast<int>(bb.getHeight());
const int matWidth = static_cast<int>(bb.getWidth());

cv::Mat curvePath = cv::Mat(matHeight, matWidth, CV_32F, 1);

for (int i = 0; i < matWidth; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matHeight; j++) {
        if (completeBandPath.contains(vec2( i+bb.getUpperLeft().x, j+bb.getUpperLeft().y ))) {
            curvePath.at<float>(j, i) = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

curvePath looks like this:

[image: curvedPath without blur]

The result after the blur looks like this (minus the upper border, that's just badly cropped):

[image: curvedPath with blur]

How can I avoid the colorful edges and blur with a nice transition from black to white on the edges?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please provide your starting image and more complete code. Thank you.

Comment: I'm confused. You say you have a black and white shape consisting of ones and zeroes, but I see a crimson curve?

Comment: Use `GaussianBlur` on your image, I don't see how it results in the colorful edges